# How can I find out if my Azure VM is running on DGX-1?

Tags: azure, nvidia, nvlink

I am trying to reset the GPU of my Azure virtual machine (`NVIDIA GPU Cloud Image` running on `Standard NV6` running Ubuntu 16.04.1) to get reproducible results on a deep learning algorithm. I found [this NVIDIA help page](https://nvidia-esp.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4642/~/how-to-reset-gpus-on-dgx-1-systems), which explains that I cannot reset individual GPUs of a DGX-1 server:

> In the case of the DGX-1 and DGX-1V platforms, individual GPU's can not be reset because they are linked via nvlink, so all the GPU's have to be reset simultaneously.

How can I find if the GPU on my Azure machine belongs to a DGX-1 server?

Comment: Please update with the OS you are using and the Azure VM series to better assist the community in answering your question.

Comment: Have you installed NVIDIA GPU Driver Extension for Linux?  You can validate the extension is installed https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/hpccompute-gpu-linux#troubleshoot-and-support

Comment: I am able to run that command but the display of the commands in your answer does not change.

Comment: Looking at the NVIDIA documentation, you need to be running on an NC VM, not a NV.  https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/gpu-cloud-computing/microsoft-azure/

Comment: Yes, I had seen that page and I am unsure which Azure lines use which NVIDIA groups of GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query the OS to tell you what device you have.  You didn't list he OS in your question to I will make the assumption it's Ubuntu.  Here are a couple commands you could try.

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12

lshw -numeric -C display
```

GPU info on the N-Series can be found here: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu

Comment: The two commands work and show, for example, `Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM204GL [Tesla M60]` and `product: GM204GL [Tesla M60]`. But they don't show if the devices are part of a DGX-1 server.